# Второй параметр вместо первого

Tags: javascript

**Объясните, пожалуйста, как явно указать нужный параметр который возвращает функция?**
**return(20,10) вместо первого получаю второй параметр.**

```
    } else if (mayoBox.checked && !spiceBox.checked) {
        console.log('mayo');
        return (20, 10);


window.onload = function() {

    var submit;

    submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.onclick = function() {
        Hamburger.prototype.calcPriceAndCalories();
    }
};

Hamburger.prototype.calcPriceAndCalories = function(price, calories) {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var totalCalories = 0;
    this.price = price;
    this.calories = calories;

totalPrice += Hamburger.prototype.burgerSize(this.price) + Hamburger.prototype.burgerStuff(this.price) + Hamburger.prototype.burgerTop(this.price);
totalCalories += this.calories;

console.log(totalPrice);
```

};

Comment: в чем смысл строки `return (20, 10);`? В ставь корректный пример кода, а не половину чего-то и нигде не используемую функцию.

Comment: Здесь я возвращаю два параметра (price, calories) когда делаю подсчет, у меня почему то берется второй параметр calories, (хотя я указываю this.price )

Comment: не угадал. здесь ты **НЕ** возвращаешь два параметра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два параметра вернуть нельзя.
Сложите их в один массив и верните его:

```js
const func = () => { return [20, 10]; }
const result = func();
console.log(result[0], result[1]);
```

Или в один объект:

```js
const func = () => { 
  const price = 10, calories = 20;
  return {price, calories}; 
}
const result = func();
console.log(result.price, func().calories);
```

Comment: Два вернуть нельзя.... как же я об этом забыл?! Массив точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так работает [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F): возвращает последний переданный параметр.

```
(20, 10) -> 10
```

Чтобы вернуть `20` нужно написать

```
return 20;
```

Comment: а если я использую два параметра, как взять именно первый?

Comment: @Pavel, ты **НЕ** используешь два параметра